# jQuery slideUp() effected for other list's slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a problem. I have some list items. When a list is clicked, it's own child will be open and an `'.open'` class will be added. When clicking on that `'.open'` class, that list's child will be hidden. So, I made my code like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.list-group li a', function() {
    // hide all other child
    $('.list-group .child').hide();
    $('.list-group li a').removeClass('open');

    // Open this list's child
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.child').slideDown();
});

$('body').on('click', '.list-group li a.open', function() {    
    // hide this list's child
    $(this).removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.child').slideUp();
});
```

But, at the time of hiding the `$(this)` list's child, it will try to `slideDown()` at first and then `slideUp()`! I can understand that this code might be responsible for this:

```
// hide all other child
$('.list-group .child').hide();
$('.list-group li a').removeClass('open');
```

How to fix this?

[Fiddle Work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/dLvhxec6/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `click` listeners are firing both times when `.open` is applied. Using a  [`:not`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp) selector in your `.on('click', '.list-group li a')` function seems to solve this

```
$('body').on('click', '.list-group li a:not(.open)', function() {
    // ....
}
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8faxxasL/)